# Typescript replaces only dots before the pipe and not after

Tags: typescript

i have a string which contains dots and i want to replace them with spaces,  for example:

i.love.dogs.|.because.its.nice

Unfortunantely its only replacing the dots before the pipe and not after. Here is my Code:

```
      let id = blogId.replace(".", " ")
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace: *If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced. [...] To perform a global search and replace, include the g switch in the regular expression.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression with the `g` (global) flag set for it to replaces all instances of it with the second argument.

So you would need to do:

```
const blogId = "i.love.dogs.|.because.its.nice"
let id = blogId.replace(/\./g, " ")

// now id is "i love dogs | because its nice"
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. **If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced**.

You can achieve your desired result with regex pattern:

`var result = blogId.replace(/\./g, " ")`

Or you could write a helper method:

```
//replace all dots in string str with a space
stripDots(str: string): string {
    let result = ""
    for (var c of str){
        if (c === ".")
            c = " ";
        result += c;
    }
    return result;
}
```